# write the mouse event on picture box when the picturebox enable has false

Tags: c#

I have a simple gif animation in my webform into picturebox1 control,this gif animation is a simple fire button ,i want when user click the picturebox1 gif animation start.
in load event i write this code:

```
picturebox1.enable=false;
```

that code stop animating with picturebox,but enable is false and i can not write mouse event click to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the picturebox disabled in the first place?
If you want the animation to start on user click you can just start with a static version of your image and replace it with the animated version on click. Then you don't need to disable the control.

If that doesn't relate to your question, could you please specify what you want to do more clearly?

[Edit]
That is what I ment. Start with a non-animated picture and change it using the on-click event like this (of course you need to create the event handler, too):

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image newImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\animated.gif");
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = newImage;
}
```

[Edit2]
That is why you start with a *static* picture (just the first frame of the gif) and replace it with an *animated* picture on click (with all frames of the gif).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"..\..\ball-noanimation.gif";
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"..\..\ball-withanimation.gif";
}
```

I tried this solution and it does exactly what I understand that you want:
 - On start it shows a static picture
 - When user clicks on the picturebox it loads the animated picture and immediately shows the animation

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and didn't change any properties of the picturebox. I created the eventhandler by double-clicking the event, creating this code: `this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);`

Comment: thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem,when the form start the picturebox start animate the my gif animation,but i want when i click on picture box the form start to animate

Comment: this solution show the picture when the click on picture box,but i want when form run the picture box show the image and when i click on button animate is start

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? And is this the solution to what you wanted to do?